# stable/mongodb helm chart authentication issue with replicaset set true

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

**Is it a request for help ?** 
Yes

**what I am trying to do?** 
I am trying to use stable/mongodb as *sub chart* in my main chart with replica set enabled

**steps performed**

- added mongodb as a sub chart in chart folder
- mention dependency of this chart in requirements.yaml

```
dependencies:
- name: mongodb
  version: "5.17.0"
  repository: "file://charts/mongodb"
```

- override sub chart values in main chart

```
mongodb:
 usePassword: true
 existingSecret: skeleton
  mongodbUsername: skeleton
  mongodbDatabase: skeleton
  replicaSet:
    ## Whether to create a MongoDB replica set for high availability or not
    enabled: true
    useHostnames: true
    name: rs0
    replicas:
      secondary: 1
      arbiter: 1
```

**- define secret for this**
in secret for skeleton

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: skeleton
type: Opaque
data:
  # mongo ha---
  mongodb-root-password: <64-bit-encoded-root-password> 
  mongodb-replica-set-key: <64-bit-encoded-Key> 
  mongodb-password: <64-bit-encoded-password>
```

**- in deployment.yaml provided headless service url  mongodb url to connect to this**

from application hosted inside same k8s cluster

`mongodb://<mongodbUsername-value-define-in-value.yaml>:<mongodb-password-value-present-in-secret>@skeleton-mongodb-headless:27017/skeleton?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0`

- **error i am getting**
  when using headless service

```
[1;30m2019-05-07 05:06:16,085[0;39m => [34mINFO [0;39m [[32mmain[0;39m] [33mcom.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger[0;39m: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[skeleton-mongodb-headless:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='rs0'}
[1;30m2019-05-07 05:06:16,085[0;39m => [34mINFO [0;39m [[32mmain[0;39m] [33mcom.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger[0;39m: Adding discovered server skeleton-mongodb-headless:27017 to client view of cluster
[1;30m2019-05-07 05:06:16,175[0;39m => [34mINFO [0;39m [[32mmain[0;39m] [33mcom.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger[0;39m: No server chosen by com.mongodb.Mongo$4@359ff4d9 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=skeleton-mongodb-headless:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
[1;30m2019-05-07 05:06:16,182[0;39m => [34mINFO [0;39m [[32mcluster-ClusterId{value='5cd11248b2cfc400017b5805', description='null'}-skeleton-mongodb-headless:27017[0;39m] [33mcom.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger[0;39m: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server skeleton-mongodb-headless:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='skeleton', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:162)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$200(SaslAuthenticator.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:46)
```

**queries**

- am i missing something for connection
- Do we need to provide key in connection url for internal    communication ?

Comment: No it is not the duplicate. These are two different helm charts . I am checking feasibility of both charts

Comment: ah right, that one is replicataset

Answer (score 3):

I am able to resolve this issue for authentication after deleting pv and Azure Disk.
I also used *release-name-mongodb* instead of *release-name-mongodb-headless*